# Autoincrement into SVG (text) and ID element of tabs

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have a series of Tabs created in SVG, however, they need an identifier so that a number can be called to fill the text of the svg consecutively.

I need to increase the text of an SVG

> `<text transform = "matrix (ignore this)" class = "st3 st4 st5"> **new number Autoincrement** </text>`

depending on the ID of the same SVG (`id = "tab-shape"`).

I tried several ways using JS, but none has given the desired result. I did the svg through Illustrator.

My code:

```js
 var menuItems = $('.main-navigation li');
 menuItems.on("click", function(event) {
  menuItems.removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
  $(".main-content").css({
   "background": $(this).data("bg-color")
  });
  event.preventDefault();
 });
   var elementList = $(".navtoIdentify");
 for (var i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
  elementList[i].attr("id", "tab-shape" + i);
 }
 $( "text" ).text("0"+i);
```

```css
 .st0{fill:#E0DEDC;}
 .st1{fill:#808B96;enable-background:new    ;}
 .st2{fill:#5D6D7E;enable-background:new    ;}
 .st3{fill:#F2F2F2;}
 .st4{font-family:'Century Gothic';}
 .st5{font-size:46px;}
 .st6{font-family:'Century Gothic';}
 .st7{font-size:14.1517px;}

 * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 body {
  padding: 1rem 3rem;
  line-height: 1.4;
  min-width: 925px;
 }
 a {
  text-decoration: none;
 }
 .main-navigation {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 0 0 .4rem;
 }
 .main-navigation ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
 }
 .main-navigation li {
  float: left;
  width: 12rem;
  height: 5rem;
  margin: 0 0 0 -1rem;
  position: relative;
 }
 .main-navigation a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 0.7rem;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
 }
 .main-navigation svg {
  width: 120%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
 }
 .main-navigation span {
  position: relative;
  padding: 1.5rem 0 0 6rem;
  z-index: 2;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 }
 .main-navigation .tab-1 {
  z-index: 9;
 }
 .main-navigation .tab-1 svg {
  fill: url(#tab-1-bg);
 }
 .main-navigation .tab-2 {
  z-index: 8;
 }
 .main-navigation .tab-2 svg {
  fill: url(#tab-2-bg);
 }
 .main-navigation .tab-3 {
  z-index: 7;
 }
 .main-navigation .tab-3 svg {
  fill: url(#tab-3-bg);
 }
 .main-navigation .tab-4 {
  z-index: 6;
 }
 .main-navigation .tab-4 svg {
  fill: url(#tab-4-bg);
 }
 .main-navigation .tab-5 {
  z-index: 5;
 }
 .main-navigation .tab-5 svg {
  fill: url(#tab-4-bg);
 }
 .main-navigation .tab-6 {
  z-index: 4;
 }
 .main-navigation .tab-6 svg {
  fill: url(#tab-4-bg);
 }
 .main-navigation .tab-7 {
  z-index: 3;
 }
 .main-navigation .tab-7 svg {
  fill: url(#tab-4-bg);
 }
 .main-navigation li.active {
  z-index: 9;
 }
 .main-content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  background: #76a0c0;
  margin: -.6rem 0 0 0;
  padding: .5rem;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
 }
 .article {
  background: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 8px;
 }
 .article h2 {
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: #76a0c0;
  margin: 0 0 0.5rem 0;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Expediente Digital</title>
</head>
<body>
<svg id="tab-shape" version="1.1" style="width: 300px; height: 300px; position: absolute; margin-left: -100%;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 284 98" style="enable-background:new 0 0 284 98;" xml:space="preserve" >
 <g>
  <path class="st0" d="M100.65,86h-62.3C22.21,86,9,72.79,9,56.65v-0.3C9,40.21,22.21,27,38.35,27h62.3
  C116.79,27,130,40.21,130,56.35v0.3C130,72.79,116.79,86,100.65,86z"/>
  <path class="st1" d="M100.65,89h-62.3C22.21,89,9,75.79,9,59.65v-0.3C9,43.21,22.21,30,38.35,30h62.3
  C116.79,30,130,43.21,130,59.35v0.3C130,75.79,116.79,89,100.65,89z"/>
  <path class="st0" d="M61.17,90l33.29-61.36c0,0,5.55-13.64,27.74-13.64S272,15,272,15v75H61.17z"/>
  <path class="st2" d="M60.41,91l33.41-58.91c0,0,5.57-13.09,27.84-13.09S272,19,272,19v72H60.41z"/>
  <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 18.7822 71.0254)" class="st3 st4 st5">#</text> 
 </g>
</svg>
<nav role="navigation" class="main-navigation">
 <ul>
  <li class="tab-1 active" data-bg-color="rgba(118, 160, 192, 1.0)">
   <a href="#Exp">
    <span> Exp</span>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 122 40">
     <use xlink:href="#tab-shape"></use>
    </svg>
   </a>
  </li>
  <li class="tab-2" data-bg-color="rgba(112, 153, 213, 1.0)">
   <a href="#General">
    <span>General</span>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 122 40">
     <use xlink:href="#tab-shape"></use>
    </svg>
   </a>
  </li>
  <li class="tab-3" data-bg-color="rgba(43, 130, 197, 1.0)">
   <a href="#Mail">
    <span>Mail</span>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 122 40">
     <use xlink:href="#tab-shape"></use>
    </svg>
   </a>
  </li>
  <li class="tab-4" data-bg-color="rgba(71, 194, 243, 1.0)">
   <a href="#Information">
    <span>Information</span>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 122 40">
     <use xlink:href="#tab-shape"></use>
    </svg>
   </a>
  </li>
  <li class="tab-5" data-bg-color="rgba(81, 194, 243, 1.0)">
   <a href="#Pres">
    <span>Pres</span>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 122 40">
     <use xlink:href="#tab-shape"></use>
    </svg>
   </a>
  </li>
  <li class="tab-6" data-bg-color="rgba(91, 194, 243, 1.0)">
   <a href="#Photos">
    <span>Photos</span>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 122 40">
     <use xlink:href="#tab-shape"></use>
    </svg>
   </a>
  </li>
  <li class="tab-7" data-bg-color="rgba(101, 194, 243, 1.0)">
   <a href="#Close">
    <span>Close</span>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 122 40">
     <use xlink:href="#tab-shape"></use>
    </svg>
   </a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</nav>
<div class="main-content">
 <article class="article">
  
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias cupiditate iusto architecto nulla sed odit error laboriosam odio numquam, voluptate deleniti earum deserunt repellat, voluptates culpa, sunt quae, quod recusandae.
 </article>
</div>


</body>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</html>
```

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: It seems you forgot to include jQuery in your code snippet, could you edit that in?

Comment: I would use only the shape. For this I would give the wrapping `<g>` an id and `<use xlink:href="#the-g"></use>`. You may need to change the viewBox value. As for the text I would use a different text element in every tab. You may translate the text in CSS like `text{transform: translate(18.7822px, 71.0254px);`